# How to create lists in list where every future list is separate by spaces in list

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, input

User provides input with spaces:

```
row = list(input())

print(row)

['1','2','3',' ','4','5','6',' ','7','8','9',' ']
```

So I need to create 'row' list into the below. The list is divided into sub-lists based on whitespace:

```
[['1','2','3'],['4','5','6'],['7','8','9']]
```

Comment: add input sample for your snippet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `str.split` to split by whitespace:

```
myinput = '123 456 789'
row = list(map(list, myinput.split()))

print(row)

[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
```

Alternatively, using a list comprehension:

```
row = [list(i) for i in myinput.split()]
```

Comment: I consider list-comprehensions more readable, but this get's the job done :) +1

Answer (score 2):

You can use[`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split the input on spaces to give a list of sub-strings.

*E.g. `'123 456 789'` would become `['123', '456', '789']`.*

Then use a [list-comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) to convert these strings into lists of characters with the `list()` constructor (as you are already familiar with).

Making the final code:

```
row = [list(s) for s in input().split()]
#[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with your list rather than the string, you can do that using [itetools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

row = ['1','2','3',' ','4','5','6',' ','7','8','9',' ']

out = [list(group) for key, group in groupby(row, lambda x: x != ' ') if key]
print(out)
# [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
```

We group the values depending on whether or not they are spaces, and only keep the groups that are not made of spaces.

Comment: `groupby(row, str.isdigit)` or `str.isspace` and `if not key`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
abc=['1','2','3',' ','4','5','6',' ','7','8','9',' ']
newList=list()
temp=list()
for i in abc:
    if(i==' '):
      newList.append(temp)
      temp=list()
    else:
      temp.append(i)
print(newList)
```

Output:

```
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
```